# Why doesn't OSM render playground elements?

Tags: openstreetmap

I've decided to start mapping playground equipment in my city for OSM, so I went to gather data, mapped the first one - and it turns out that OSM does not render the playground=* elements: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/51.13651/17.04777

This is how it looks on JOSM:
[image: The playground elements in JOSM]

And it also renders (as shapes only) when I enable map data in OSM: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/51.13651/17.04777&layers=D

However I see that playground elements are rendered in other places, ex. here a playground=sandpit is rendered in a german city: https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/9296255161#map=19/48.27857/10.97406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying OSM data is rendered to map tile images using a styling process so that people can produce different-looking maps from the same data.

The stylesheet that is being used to render the default openstreetmap.org map styles some things and not others. That's the way it is. There seems to be a lot of discussion about how to style playgrounds, including the occasional "You only think this is not important because you don't have kids" comment, but overall it is good-natured if somewhat technical in places. But that's the OSM community for you. Have a read here:

https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/pull/3161

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Maybe I could do a pull request with a "parental" layer for osm, like we have public transport layers etc.